# remove Anaconda environment with no name/warning message after TensorFlow is upgraded

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, deep-learning

I upgraded the tensorflow, python and setup an new deep learning environment.

## Problem 1

The new environment can work, but  I get the following messages when I activate the environment.

```
Erick MINGW64 /z/Erick/CNN_Demo/noise_reduction (master)
$ source activate
(base) 
Erick MINGW64 /z/Erick/CNN_ Demo/noise_reduction (master)
$ conda activate z:\Erick/CNN_ Demo \noise_reduction\.conda

EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: z: Erick/CNN_ Demo noise_reduction.conda
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

(base) 
Erick MINGW64 /z/ Erick/CNN_ Demo/noise_reduction (master)
```

After type the command  `$ conda info --envs`, I got the following information

```
conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Erick\AppData\Local\anaconda3        
tf                       C:\Users\Erick\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf
                         z:\Erick/CNN_Demo\noise_reduction\.conda
```

I have tried the following commands to remove the 3rd one with no name, but they don't work

`conda env remove -p z:\Erick/CNN_Demo\noise_reduction\.conda`

`conda env remove -p z:\Erick/CNN_Demo\noise_reduction\`

`conda env remove -p z:\Erick/CNN_Demo\noise_reduction`

## Problem 2

I also get the following message when I ran my codes. Do you think I need to fix the following problems? Thanks.

```
Z:\Zhou_ZX\CNN_CTCIC\noise_reduction\GARNET_alpha\core\scripts\PBAR_callbacks.py:16: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if __name__ == '__main__' or __package__ is '':

<>:110: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

<>:114: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

C:\Users\Erick\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\adam.py:114: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)

<ipython-input-3-bddb21d030e0>:110: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if arch_sel is 'ResNet':
<ipython-input-3-bddb21d030e0>:114: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if arch_sel is 'UNet':
2023-06-21 13:38:27.269647: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-06-21 13:38:28.930986: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9825 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA TITAN V, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
```

Comment: $ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\M249213\AppData\Local\anaconda3        
tf                       C:\Users\M249213\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf
                         z:\Zhou_ZX\CNN_CTCIC\noise_reduction\.conda

Comment: I think the third env is more like a corrupted one. Can you try creating a fresh environment with the same configuration? Might work. And for your 2nd problem, it seems that is because of differences in dependencies. There's no harm in replacing 'is' with '==' though.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. The 3rd env is based on old version of tensorflow(version 1.15) and python. Now I am using tensorflow 2.10.  I think I cannot create an env with same settings as the 3rd one.

Comment: In that case, if you are aware of the dependencies that you need for your current code to function (possibly a requirements.txt file or so). You can create a fresh env with the required Python version and then pip install the required dependencies. You can temporarily ignore the corrupted env.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just omit this environment as suggested by Dev Bhuyan.

Here I learned a lesson that may be also helpful to others.

Please remove all the virtual environment before you make updates on your software (like python, tensorflow) and create a new environment. Otherwise you may meet the same problem as I met.